# Notifications depends of Android version?

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

With new Android Jelly Bean apear new tools for Notification area. Wonder if I got my old app I can validate the user system and set up the notifications depends of it 4.1 or less?

Thanks for any good ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

Using new Notification API with backward compatibility is possible.
See links below :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html

Comment: Have you got any example of using it? Thanks.